# Smoothing clicks when scrubbing/seeking through the audio

Tags: audio, audio-processing, smoothing

I have a buffer of *N* samples from which I'm playing a loop of *L* samples *(L <= N)* starting from sample *S*. The reading position is calculated as *(S + P) % N* where *P* is current playhead position which is advanced as *P = (P + 1) % L*. Adjusting *S* during playback I'm getting clicks and I'm looking for the ways to eliminate them. I've tried doing linear interpolation, however didn't get desired result - not sure whether I'm doing it wrong or it's just not the right tool for the job.

The platform is Daisy Seed board (STM32H7 480Mhz).

I would highly appreciate an advice on what's the possible way of doing this.

Comment: So you wanna shuttle back and forth without pitch change, right?  This will be about time scaling it can be done pretty good without a frequency-domain method (like phase vocoder), but it's gonna be about splicing and cross-fading.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes, without pitch change. I guess I understand what you mean. Thanks for the advice!